# How to get current token in yyerror?

Tags: error-handling, syntax-error, token, yacc, lex

My problem is that the message passed to `yyerror` is already formatted (i.e. it is actually an English explanation what went wrong), and what I would like to get is just the current token (i.e. the one before the error pseudo-token).

So how to get it?

I use gplex/gppg which are lex/yacc implementations in C#.

---

I am sorry for not being 100% precise -- what I need is token (symbol) not the body (text) which was matched (by the token).

Let's say I have a rule `[A-Za-z0-9_]+` constitutes an `ID`. So I would like to get token `ID` not a `foobar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no standard, but bison and most versions of yacc store the current token in `yychar`.  Unfortunately, this is generally a local variable (of `yyparse`), so you can't access it in other functions (such as `yyerror`), only in parser actions.

It might be helpful if you say WHY you want the current token -- its not generally a useful peice of information.  You mention the error pseudo-token, which makes no sense as that is associated with error recovery, not errors as such -- by the time it comes into the picture normally a bunch of tokens from the input have been discarded.

Comment: Thank you. I want the current token to display custom message, so either I parse back the message, or get the components of it, and display my own. And I have to have my own message for sake of automatic testing with old project. Otherwise with each tool (Bison, Yacc, CUP, you name it) you would have to jump big hoops to be sure if your output is still the same. Error pseudo-token makes sense, I  mentioned it to avoid the answer "hey, the current token is error token".

Comment: @macias: For custom error messages, generally what you want is `yytext` -- the text of the last matched token, rather than the token code.  But you explicitly say you DON'T want the text.

Comment: Gosh, thank you for telling me what I want. Please, respect others needs, the fact something is unusual, does not mean you have to force this or that solution or POV. And I need token code, period.

Answer (score 2):

Found this in an old project of mine, with a redefined yyerror:

```
int yyerror (char *msg) {
  printf("oha, %s: '%s' in line %d\n", msg, yytext, yylineno);
  return 0;
}
```

This was a c++-project using flex/bison, and the interesting thing i think you can find in yytext.

Comment: Thank you, I was not precise, sorry. `yytext` gives the content of the token, not the token itself.

Comment: Hmm. Looked again in that old project, and what i did there in the lexer file is instead of "{" return LCB; I used "{"            return isWat(LCB);.
In that isWat-routine i check for an error-flag which I set in the above yyerror-routine (that code i removed to avoid confusion), and if set just output the token id. Of course its a little bit of work, coz every token is returned thru this isWat-routine. But it worked. But maybe there are better solutions to that...

Comment: Thank you again. So far I made a little hackery -- I took a peek how the message is formated, and get the direct access to the field of the token.